# Excel - Filter Table based off Start Date, End Date cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet that is pulling a Dataset from a SQL Server table.

What I'm needing to do is include Start Date and End Date cells for the user to be able to easier filter the data.

In the dataset results there is a Date Column called ShiftDate, and I need to filter on that.

[image]

So entering dates above (In Sheet2) would filter the table (In sheet1) based off the Shift Date column:

[image]

I've been searching and searching and have been unable to find any code/formula that would do this.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Could you provide a dataset sample - it is not clear what you are asking for ...

Comment: If you want the table on sheet2 automatically to be filtered whenever the user changes the dates on sheet1 then you need VBA. If you have Excel 365 and want the filtered result e.g. on sheet1 you can use the new `FILTER`-function.

Comment: Vba would be a quick way to manage this. Otherwise you could use pivot tables and slicers instead of manually entered dates

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Power Query to pull the data from SQL Server, you could pass 2 date parameters into the query and filter the results each time you refresh.

Here is an article showing how this works:

https://exceleratorbi.com.au/pass-excel-parameter-power-query/

You could then add some VBA to refresh the table each time A2 or B2 are updated.